# Shouldn't red and blue have some sort of symmetry?

Tags: coloring, ramsey-theory

Recently I've encounter a problem:

Every space point is colored either red or blue. Show that among the squares with
side 1 in this space there is at least one with three red vertices or at least one with four blue vertices.

The solution is somehow hard-to-think-of (at least for me):

Denote by B the property that there is a unit square with four blue vertices.
Case 1: All points of space are blue ⇒ B.
Case 2: There exists a red point P1. Make of P1 the vertex of a pyramid with equal
edges and the square P2P3P4P5 as base.
Case 2.1: The four points Pi, i = 2, 3, 4, 5 are blue ⇒ B.
Case 2.2: One of the points Pi, i = 2, 3, 4, 5 is red, say P2. Make of P1P2 a lateral edge of an equilateral prism, with the remaining vertices P6, P7, P8, P9.
Case 2.2.1: The four points Pj, j = 6, 7, 8, 9 are blue ⇒ B.
Case 2.2.2: One of the points Pj, j = 6, 7, 8, 9 is red, say P6. Then P1, P2, and P6 are three red vertices of a unit square.

But here comes the question: shouldn't red and blue have some sort of symmetry? Can we assert from the above-mentioned proof and from symmetry that there is at least one with FOUR red vertices or at least one with four blue vertices? I fail to figure out whether this is true or false, but I simply find it wierd to differentiate between red and blue.

Comment: Sure there is a symmetry.  You could switch blue and red to conclude that there is either a unit square with $3$ blue vertices or one with $4$ red ones.

Comment: The comment of @lulu describes the symmetrical relationship.  The statement that there is either a square with 4 red vertices or one with 4 blue ones is a stronger statement.  Proving the *weaker* assertion does not prove the *stronger* assertion.

Comment: Note:  I do not agree with the downvote.  This is a perfectly sensible question.  On its face it looks like a case of broken symmetry, though I do not believe that it is.  As to the question of whether or not there must be a unit square of a single color, I have no idea. Sometimes these questions admit clever solutions, and sometimes they don't.

Comment: So you mean there may exist both a unit square with 3 blue vertices and one with 3 red vertices, but no unit square with all 4 vertices of the same color, right?

Comment: Yes, that's what I mean.  But, to stress:  as far as I know it may be the case that there has to be a unit square of a single color.  That's a separate question.

Comment: I get it. Thank you for your support!